# Spring Boot YML Config Class Inheritance

Tags: spring-boot, yaml

Is it possible to use inheritance in Spring Boot YML configuration classes? If so, how would that be accomplished?

For example:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="my-config")
public class Config {
    List<Vehicle> vehicles;
}
```

And the class (or interface) "Vehicle" has two implementations: Truck and Car. So the YAML might look like:

```
my.config.vehicles:
  -
    type: car
    seats: 3
  -
    type: truck
    axles: 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think it is possible (at least not that I know of). You could however design your code as follow:

#### Inject the properties into a Builder object

Define an object with all properties, which we'll call the `VehicleBuilder` (or factory, you choose its name).
The `VehicleBuilders` are injected from the Yaml.
You can then retrieve each builder's vehicle in a `@PostConstruct` block. The code:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="my-config")
@Component
public class Config {
    private List<VehicleBuilder> vehicles = new ArrayList<VehicleBuilder>();
    private List<Vehicle> concreteVehicles;
    
    public List<VehicleBuilder> getVehicles() {
        return vehicles;
    }
    
    public List<Vehicle> getConcreteVehicles() {
        return concreteVehicles;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    protected void postConstruct(){
        concreteVehicles = vehicles.stream().map(f -> f.get())
                                   .collect(Collectors.<Vehicle>toList());
    }
}
```

The builder:

```
public class VehicleBuilder {
    private String type;
    private int seats;
    private int axles;

    public Vehicle get() {
        if ("car".equals(type)) {
            return new Car(seats);
        } else if ("truck".equals(type)) {
            return new Trunk(axles);
        }
        throw new AssertionError();
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public void setSeats(int seats) {
        this.seats = seats;
    }

    public void setAxles(int axles) {
        this.axles = axles;
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the input. This is similar to the solution I was already using... I was just hoping there was a more streamlined way to do it. :-)