# Polymorphic @ConfigurationProperties

Tags: java, spring-boot, polymorphism, yaml, deserialization

Consider this `application.yml`:

```
shapes:
   - type: "square"
     side: 4
   - type: "circle"
     radius: 6
```

with the following Java hierarchy:

```
public abstract class Shape {
     private String type;
     ...
}

public class Square extends Shape {
     private float side;
     ...
}

public class Circle extends Shape {
     private float radius;
     ...
}
```

Using the base class in `@ConfigurationProperties` class does not work:

```
 @Configuration
 @ConfigurationProperties
 public class ShapesProperties { 
      // BindException
      private List<Shape> shapes;
      ...
 }
```

Is this scenario supported by Spring? I've read about `ConversionService`, `Binder`, `Converter<S, T>` but I'm not sure if they can solve this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Boot YML Config Class Inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40367935/spring-boot-yml-config-class-inheritance)