# Spring Boot Is it possible to bind an implementation of interface to @ConfigurationProperties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin

Good day everyone!

Is it possible to have an interface as configuration property of **Spring Boot** application, so that Spring Boot could choose implementation based on object properties?

For example, I have a next externalized configuration described in **yaml** file:

```yaml
props:
    elements:
        - name: element1
          uniqueProperty1: value1
        - name: element2
          uniqueProperty2: value2
```

And next class annotated with `@ConfigurationProperties` and list of elements, implementing `Element` interface, as property with some implementation classes (code in **Kotlin**):

```kotlin
@ConfigurationProperties(value = "props")
class ConfigProperties() {
    var elements: List<Element> = emptyList()
}

interface Element {
    val name: String
}

class ElementImpl1 : Element {
    override val name: String = ""
    val uniqueProperty1: String = ""
}

class ElementImpl2 : Element {
    override val name: String = ""
    val uniqueProperty2: String = ""
}
```

When I run my application, next error occurs:
`org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindException: Failed to bind properties under 'props.elements' to java.util.List<Element>`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Boot YML Config Class Inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40367935/spring-boot-yml-config-class-inheritance)