# Spring Configuration Properties - Polymorphic Objects in same List

Tags: java, spring-boot, configurationproperties

I am trying to read a list of configuration items from `application.yaml` into a configuration bean via `@ConfigurationProperties`. The list may consist of objects with a defined base type:

```
@ConfigurationProperties("myapp")
public class MyConfiguration {
   private Set<Point> points;
}

public abstract class Point {
  private String name;
}

public class QuantityPoint extends Point {
  private Number value;
}

public class StatePoint extends Point {
  private String state;
}
```

Here an example `application.yaml` as I imagine it:

```
myapp:
  points:
  - name: foo
    value: 5
  - name: bar
    state: bar
```

I have found some posts which I thought are solving this exact question, but nothing suggested there has worked so far. I tried playing with `ConfigurationProperties("myapp.points")` on the subtypes on `Point` but as said: nothing has worked.

To be honest, I wonder how the parser should be able to distinguish the types. There must be something like a `type` argument missing similar to how we convert entities to json with Jackson.

At the moment, I am getting instances of `Point` (when I remove the `abstract` modifier) and the fields `value` and `state` are lost.

**EDIT**

I think I made some progress in finding out what needs to be done. Apparently, Spring is using SnakeYaml to parse the file and that library uses yaml tags to indicate type information so that my yaml should look something like

```
myapp:
  points:
  - !!foo
    name: foo
    value: 5
  - !!bar
    name: bar
    state: bar
```

There are some builtin tags but I would need to register my own. I found information how to write a custom Constructor by extending `AbstractConstruct` but I couldn't find anything on how to register this with the instance of `Yaml` that's set up by springboot.

Am I at least on the right track here?

**EDIT**

I noticed that the `ConstructorException` from snakeyaml comes so early in the startup process, it's probably not possible to to add my `SafeConstructor` to the process:

```
@Component
public class FooConstructor extends SafeConstructor {

    public FooConstructor() {
        this.yamlConstructors.put(new Tag("!foo"), new ConstructFoo());
    }
    
    private class ConstructFoo extends AbstractConstruct {
        @Override
        public Object construct(Node node) {
            String val = (String) constructScalar((ScalarNode) node);
            System.out.println(val);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

```
06:48:29.380 [restartedMain] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.ConstructorException: could not determine a constructor for the tag !state
 in 'reader', line 5, column 5:
      - !foo
```

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot#3-custom-converter

Comment: The example in your link converts the string "john,2000" to an Employee object. That's not my scenario.

Comment: You scenario is to convert a `Map<String, Object>` to a `Point`. It's not very different

Comment: Hmm that's a good point. Haven't thought of it that way. I'll give it a try, thanks!

Comment: The `Converter<Map<String, Object>, Point>` is never called

Comment: Have you checked with adding the constructor for `QuantityPoint` and `StatePoint`

Comment: As far as I understand, the Constructor must be added to the `Yaml` object but I don't see how to get my hands on the one used to read the application.yml

Comment: I suspect that trying to make SnakeYAML do the conversion is going to throw off Spring's autoconfiguration anyway, as Spring wants to control the conversion from a tree of nested Lists/Maps to POJO by itself. Also, Spring is built to accept .properties files where it can accept a .yaml, so I wouldn't expect Spring to be built to exploit any SnakeYaml feature that isn't available in .properties files. Even if it worked, a future version of Spring might break that approach.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Boot YML Config Class Inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40367935/spring-boot-yml-config-class-inheritance)